# html,body: min-height 100% not applying to CSS3 box-shadow

Tags: html, css

When using a background color and a box-shadow (inset) for the body-element, and setting

```
hmtl,body {min-height:100%;}
```

only the background-color is displayed correctly. In case the page's content is shorter than the browser-window, the box-shadow stops earlier than the background-color.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
html {height:100%;}
body {min-height:100%;}
```